# How can I test to see if a player is NOT in a boat?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

MADEUP, but with a real account. I'm making a Mini game for my friends realm called IceBoat,which is pretty self explanatory, but there is an essential command that I can't find anywhere! I tried modifying a command to do what I want, and here is my modified command:

```
testfor @e {type!=RootVehicle:{Entity:{id:Boat}}}
```

and it gives me this error:

> The entered UUID provided is in an invalid format.

With slight variations of this command, (I mean changing location of type and brackets) I get the same error. So, how can I create a testfor to see if anyone is NOT in a boat?

Comment: Just to note, the `!` character is not recognised in the Minecraft command syntax

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use exclamation marks in Minecraft commands?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/288688/how-to-use-exclamation-marks-in-minecraft-commands)

Answer (score 0):

For players:

```
/scoreboard players tag @a add inboat {RootVehicle:{id:"Boat"}}
```

will add the "inboat" tag to all players in a boat.
You can then execute commands on players not in boats using the `@a[tag=!inboat]` selector.

Comment: Only players use the `RootVehicle` tag. Using `@e` as the selector would only serve to increase the work the server needs to do, so `@a` should be used instead. You would also have to remove that tag if it exists first in the event the player leaves the boat. And you can further reduce strain by only targeting relevant players (such as `/scoreboard players tag @a[tag=inboat] remove inboat`).

Comment: Ok so use a scoreboard team type thing, and teleport everyone in a certain team... ok, ill try it!

Comment: It gave me the same error... I even noticed a mistake in your command, fixed it, and moved it around...